# creating HTML content on server side using templates

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

What is the possible solution of creating the HTML content on the server side from a template(.eex).

Comment: What? What do you wanna do?

Comment: i have a template(.html.eex) which renders html to the page, i have to convert that page to pdf. i know the lib that converts the pdf, but what i want is the exact html content on the server side so that i can convert it. Thanks @JustMichael

Comment: I believe it's possible and should be easy enough, you could probably use something like `Phoenix.View.render_to_string` or something similar.

Comment: @JustMichael thank you. i think you should put that in answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible and quite easy, `Phoenix.View` module provides a number of functions that do exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

```
html= Phoenix.View.render_to_string(MyAPP.Web.DefaultView,"template.html", %{details: somedetails_details})
```